# Could not find the shared folder of virtualbox in guest OS

Tags: virtualbox

My host OS is mac, and My guest OS is centos. Now I'd like share one folder of mac with centos. I did it via shared folder of virtualbox. It is supposed to be in  folder /media, but I could not find it. Does anyone know where can I find it. Thanks

Comment: When you share it, make sure that the VM is not running and that you tick `auto-mount`. Then start the VM and if you shared a folder called `/tmp` from your Mac it will appear as `/media/sf_tmp` in your VM.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell , The problem is I did that, but could not find it under /media

Comment: The only other reason I know that would cause that not to work is if you have not installed *"Guest Additions"* properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, I installed "Guest Additions" to solve it:

1. Menu Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD image ...
2. it appears in the VM "Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Addition" icon
3. Open it and start the installation
4. Menu Devices -> Shared Folders
5. In the folder list, select and confirm a directory on the host machine
6. Restart VM